# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBonusException

Tags: java

Запускал простенькую программку (откомпилировалось успешно) и тут такая ошибка:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBonusException: 20 at Имя моей программы.main(Имя моей программы:14)`

А вот код программы

```
class TwoDArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int twoD[][] = new int[4][5];
        int i, j, k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                twoD[i][j] = k;
                k++;
            }
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                System.out.println(twoD[i][k] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vikkingg, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: bonus >.< , хотя бы просто скопировали название ошибки

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (вернее называть этот объект исключением) возникает в тех случаях, когда была предпринята попытка обратиться к элементу массива по индексу, выходящей за рамки массива. Иными словами, если в  массиве 5 элементов, то при обращении к 20-му и произойдёт эта ошибка.
В данному случае, у Вас в 13 строке именно это и происходит:

```
twoD[i][k]
```

Исправьте k на счётчик цикла j:

```
twoD[i][j]
```

Comment: о, точно что там к делает))

Comment: Учитесь на здоровье :-)

Comment: @pkamozin замечание @Viacheslav Вы проигнорировали -- и правильно. Такое название намного симпатичней.

Comment: @alexlz, спасибо. Не включена рассылка новых комментариев.
По поводу названия исключения - "съел" и не заметил после рабочего дня :"-)